# Speech Synthesis API Highlight words as they are spoken

Tags: javascript, html, speech-synthesis

Currently, I'm making a simple app where text is spoken using the speech synthesis API.  I want to highlight the words (bold) as they are being spoken.  I currently have a very basic implementation doing this using the 'onboundary' event.  However, I'm wondering if there's a better/nicer way of doing it, as my implementation is based on a few presumptions.

```
var words;
var wordIdx;
var text;
var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
utterance.lang = 'en-UK';
utterance.rate = 1;

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('textarea').innerText = 'This is a text area.  It is used as a simple test to check whether these words are highlighted as they are spoken using the web speech synthesis API (utterance).';

    document.getElementById('playbtn').onclick = function(){
        text    = document.getElementById('textarea').innerText;
        words   = text.split(' ');
        wordIdx = 0;

        utterance.text = text;
        speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
    }

    utterance.onboundary = function(event){
        var e = document.getElementById('textarea');
        var it = '';

        for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            if(i === wordIdx){
                it += '<strong>' + words[i] + '</strong>';
            } else {
                it += words[i];
            }

            it += ' ';
        }

        e.innerHTML = it;
        wordIdx++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Your code doesn't work, but i just wrote an example that works the way you want. Open the fiddle to see it working

```
var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var wordIndex = 0;
var global_words = [];
utterance.lang = 'en-UK';
utterance.rate = 1;


document.getElementById('playbtn').onclick = function(){
    var text    = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
    var words   = text.split(" ");
    global_words = words;
    // Draw the text in a div
    drawTextInPanel(words);
    spokenTextArray = words;
    utterance.text = text;
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
};

utterance.onboundary = function(event){
    var e = document.getElementById('textarea');
    var word = getWordAt(e.value,event.charIndex);
    // Show Speaking word : x
    document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = word;
    //Increase index of span to highlight
    console.info(global_words[wordIndex]);

    try{
        document.getElementById("word_span_"+wordIndex).style.color = "blue";
    }catch(e){}

    wordIndex++;
};

utterance.onend = function(){
        document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = "";
    wordIndex = 0;
    document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML = "";
};

// Get the word of a string given the string and the index
function getWordAt(str, pos) {
    // Perform type conversions.
    str = String(str);
    pos = Number(pos) >>> 0;

    // Search for the word's beginning and end.
    var left = str.slice(0, pos + 1).search(/\S+$/),
        right = str.slice(pos).search(/\s/);

    // The last word in the string is a special case.
    if (right < 0) {
        return str.slice(left);
    }
    // Return the word, using the located bounds to extract it from the string.
    return str.slice(left, right + pos);
}

function drawTextInPanel(words_array){
console.log("Dibujado");
        var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
    for(var i = 0;i < words_array.length;i++){
        var html = '<span id="word_span_'+i+'">'+words_array[i]+'</span>&nbsp;';
        panel.innerHTML += html;
    }
}
```

Please play with the following fiddle :

[Highlight spoken word SpeechSynthesis Javascript fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ourcodeworld/9k0z6m14/4/)

It highlight the spoken word in div with blue, you can customize it with bold style, but the important is the idea.

**Note:** remember that the `onboundary` event is only triggered for the native (local) voice synthesis. Changing the voice as specified in the Google Examples (i.e **Google UK English Male**) for a google remote voice, will make your code fail as the SpeechSynthesis API seems to only play a sound generated by the google servers.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the note about the onboundary event, or is that simply something you've noticed?  I've come across the same thing and am trying to find out if this is something that should be supported.

Comment: Here is a slightly modified version of your answer that selects the words inside a text area https://stackoverflow.com/a/50285928/441016.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I wanted to implement Text-To-Speech on the web. Then I do research:

[See my complete research about this](https://github.com/albirrkarim/react-speech-highlight-demo/)

### This is what I got:

#### Using [Web Speech Synthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis)

When we using built in browser web speech synthesis API its free but, it comes with various problem. like robot like sound, wrong spelling, etc.. [see all problems](https://github.com/albirrkarim/react-speech-highlight-demo/blob/main/PROBLEMS.md)

#### Using Audio File

We can achieve good human like voices by using audio file. But, when we want to perform TTS with audio file we need transcript timestamp like this:

```
[
  {
    text: "hello world",
    start: 0
    end: 1.2
  }
]
```

The transcript timestamp generation is theoretically require machine learning.

### Solution

Then i decide make [React / Vanilla Speech Highlight](https://github.com/albirrkarim/react-speech-highlight-demo)
npm package that can combines all the benefits from TTS with [Web Speech Synthesis API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis) and TTS using Audio File.

You can make the audio file using various speech synthesis API provider like [ElevenLabs](https://elevenlabs.io/?from=partnermurray4444), Google Cloud TTS, Amazon Polly, and Open AI.

How about transcript timestamp to perform TTS using an audio file?

I make transcript timestamp detection engine. So my package can read the audio and produce transcript timestamp.

This package supports both react and vanilla js (native javascript).

Here the [demo website](https://react-speech-highlight.vercel.app) you can try the capability.

[See my complete research about this](https://github.com/albirrkarim/react-speech-highlight-demo/)

## Example Code

#### Styling the highlighter

File `App.css`

```css
.highlight-spoken {
  color: black !important;
  background-color: #ff6f00 !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.highlight-sentence {
  color: #000000 !important;
  background-color: #ffe082 !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

#### The code example

File `App.js`

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { markTheWords, useTextToSpeech } from "react-speech-highlight";

export default function App() {
  const text = "Some Input String";
  const textEl = useRef();
  const lang = "en-US";

  const { controlHL, statusHL, prepareHL, spokenHL } = useTextToSpeech({
    disableSentenceHL: false,
    disableWordHL: false,
    autoScroll: false,
    lang: lang,
  });

  const textHL = useMemo(() => markTheWords(text), [text]);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={textEl}>
        <div
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: textHL,
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>

      <PanelControlTTS
        isPlay={statusHL == "play" || statusHL == "calibration"}
        play={() => {
          if (statusHL == "pause") {
            controlHL.resume();
          } else {
            controlHL.play(
              textEl.current
            );
          }
        }}
        pause={controlHL.pause}
        stop={controlHL.stop}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

#### Sample TTS Control

File `PanelControlTTS.js`

```
export default function PanelControlTTS({ isPlay, play, pause, stop }) {
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (isPlay) {
            pause();
          } else {
            play();
          }
        }}
      >
        {isPlay ? "pause" : "play"}
      </button>

      {isPlay && <button onClick={stop}>stop</button>}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React you can use [`tts-react`](https://github.com/morganney/tts-react). Here's an example loading it from a CDN, but it can also be used as an NPM package.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>tts-react UMD example</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tts-react@1.2.0/dist/umd/tts-react.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
      const { TextToSpeech, useTts } = TTSReact
      const CustomTTS = ({ children }) => {
        const { play, ttsChildren } = useTts({ children, markTextAsSpoken: true })

        return (
          <>
            <button onClick={() => play()}>Play</button>
            <div>{ttsChildren}</div>
          </>
        )
      }

      root.render(
        <>
          <CustomTTS>
            <p>Highlight words as they are spoken.</p>
          </CustomTTS>
          <TextToSpeech size="small" markTextAsSpoken>
            <p>Highlight words as they are spoken.</p>
          </TextToSpeech>
        </>
      )
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```