# How to remove the blue rectangle when element is focused?

Tags: html, css

How to remove the blue rectangle when element is focused? I've seen similar questions but those question link to an external site. My question includes a snippet that can be tested on SO.

Here is what I get when text area is focused:

[image]

Here is what I want when text area is focused:
[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```css
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#textarea  {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
  height:160px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:-0.2em;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">yo</textarea>
```

I have already looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element).
I have also looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element).

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258647/changing-the-highlight-color-when-selecting-text-in-an-html-text-input

Comment: Thank you. I looked at those and they don't provide a working solution. They use the same code I have mentioned here. I've found an answer though.

Comment: The question linked is the same question. I've copied over my answer. This question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
   outline: none !important; }
```

Comment: This didn't make any changes for me.

Comment: I found the problem. It does work in Safari but  not in Firefox. Setting the border to 0 removes the border completely in Firefox. It seems matching the text area border make it appear that the focus outline is gone but it is actually switching borders to the same border style. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution changes the defined border value of the focus style for the selected elements. I've effectively made the focus border match the text area border:

[image]

```css
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline:none;
    border:1px solid gray;
}

#textarea  {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
  height:160px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:-0.2em;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">yo</textarea>
```

Comment: ... or just don't screw with the accessibility of your website and add a real focus style. "[*If an element can be interacted with, it must have a visible focus indicator. Provide obvious focus styling if the default focus style is removed.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline)"

Comment: I appreciate  your response but you don't know my purpose. My site is actually for accessibility lol. It's a text to speech screen reader. When text is read each word is highlighted. The textarea has to be focused for the word to be highlighted but it's not the subject of focus. The current spoken word is the focus. Check it out  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284816/is-it-possible-to-select-the-word-that-is-being-read-while-using-the-speechsynth